# How can I use the jQuery UI color animation to fade an element to a color then back to its original color?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the following right now:

```
$('input[value=NEW]:hidden').parent().parent().animate({
                            backgroundColor: "#FF9933",
                            duration: 500
                        }).animate({
                            duration: 500,
                            backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"
                        });
```

It seems like this ~almost~ works but it doesn't seem to be waiting the full time.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your solution seems to work fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/7kKvW/ Which version of jQuery do you have, and do you have jQueryUI installed? It is required to animate color transitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your code seems to work for me (see my comment under your question).

Although I'm not sure what you mean by *"it doesn't seem to be waiting the full time"*.

Do you mean that you want a delay before the second animation?

If so, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/7kKvW/1/

```
$('input[value=NEW]:hidden').parent().parent().animate({
    backgroundColor: "#FF9933",
    duration: 500
})  // delay the next item in the queue by 500ms
  .delay(500).animate({
    duration: 500,
    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"
});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/delay/ *(requires jQuery 1.4 or later)*

Answer (score 0):

I found the following approach a little bit smoother for items that may begin animating within the duration of the two animation events. Also, Instead of chaining the event with a delay, I added it as an `complete` function so that if the first one is stopped, the second doesn't still happen.

Also, the duration doesn't have to be included as an object. `Duration` is the default, second parameter to the `animate` effect.

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
// Stop makes sure any previous animations on this 
// elements aren't making the display 'flashing' in unexpected ways
$(jqueryLookup).stop(true, true, true).animate({
    backgroundColor:"#F93",
}, 1000, function() {
    // Begin the second animation upon completing the first
    $(this).animate({
        backgroundColor:"#FFF"
    }, 500);
});
```

Hope that helps you!